# incompatible pointer types passing 'char *(char *)' to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)()'

Tags: c, ruby

I need to extend my ruby code using C code. I have this function on my c file:

```
char * generateIt(char *valor) {
  struct NESSIEstruct w;
  u8 digest[DIGESTBYTES];

  int i;
  for(i=0; valor[i]!='\0'; ++i);
  int sizeo = i;

  NESSIEinit(&w);
  NESSIEadd((u8*)valor, 8*sizeo, &w);
  NESSIEfinalize(&w, digest);
  return displayIt(digest, DIGESTBYTES);
}
```

And to make it available to Ruby, at the same file, I have this:

```
void
Init_whirlpool(){
  rb_mWhirlpool = rb_define_module("Whirlpool");
  rb_cClass = rb_define_class_under(rb_mWhirlpool, "Class", rb_cObject);
  rb_define_method(rb_cClass, "generate", generateIt, 1);
}
```

But, when I try do run: make, I get this warning:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Patricio:whirlpool psantos$ make compiling whirlpool.c
>   whirlpool.c:2021:43: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char
>   *(char *)' to parameter of type 'VALUE (*)()' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]   rb_define_method(rb_cClass,
>   "generate", generateIt, 1);
>                                             ^~~~~~~~~~ /Users/psantos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1290:48:
>   note: passing argument to parameter here void
>   rb_define_method(VALUE,const char*,VALUE(*)(ANYARGS),int);
>                                                  ^ 1 warning generated.

Error image: (to be more clear)

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`rb_define_method()` takes a Ruby `VALUE` type.

```
void rb_define_method(
    VALUE klass, 
    const char *name, 
    VALUE (*func)(ANYARGS), 
    int argc
);
```

- [*Extending Ruby*](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) (from upper left menu)
- [Ruby objects](http://blog.x-aeon.com/2012/12/13/the-ruby-c-api-basics/#TRCAB_Ruby)
- [github.com/silverhammermba, Ruby C API - VALUE](http://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/c/#value)

Comment: see that my function "generateIt" return a char *. If I change the function type do VALUE, how can I return a String (char *)?

Comment: @PSantos: If the `char*` is a C-string then `rb_str_new2(the_c_string);`

Comment: @PSantos: Your signature for the function should likely be something like: `VALUE generateIt(VALUE self, VALUE valor)` – look at examples under first link in answer.